# Cumulative sum with list comprehension

Tags: python

I have a list of integers:

```
x = [3, 5, 2, 7]
```

And I want to create a new list where the `nth` element is the sum of elements in `x` from `0` to `n-1`.

This would result in:

```
y = [0, 3, 8, 10]
```

How can I do this with list comprehension, without running a loop?

Comment: List comprehension consists of a loop.

Comment: But it's sideways, and if loops are anything like hats, they're cooler when they're sideways.

Answer (score 11):

How about without a loop and without a list comprehension? Sadly only Python 3:

```
>>> x = [3, 5, 2, 7]
>>> from itertools import accumulate
>>> [0] + list(accumulate(x[:-1]))
[0, 3, 8, 10]
```

Update: Here's an O(n) list comprehension solution:

```
>>> s = [0]
>>> [s.append(s[0]+n) or s.pop(0) for n in x]
[0, 3, 8, 10]
```

But I only wanted to show that that's possible without too much effort. I think `accumulate` or a for loop are much better.

Comment: This is specific to  python 3

Comment: I know. But ok, I mentioned it and added a solution that works in Python 2 as well.

Comment: It's worth noting that this empties the original `list`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Huh? What? No it doesn't.

Comment: Oops; I saw the `pop` and freaked out.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: I think you're mixing up `s` and `x`. `s` is just a temporary, used to simulate variable assignment in a context that only allows expressions. `x` is the original list, and it doesn't get mutated.

Comment: I tested the methods here as well as my method. For a list of 50 million elements, your first method took 26 seconds, your second method took 35 seconds, and my method took 30 seconds.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 There's no way your method only took 30 seconds for that. No. Way.

Comment: The large `list` I used was the original `x` multiplied to a length of 50m, if you'd like to try it. My tests were functions that consist of saving a `perf_counter()` call, generating the list comprehension without saving it, and then printing the current `perf_counter()` minus the saved one.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: 30 seconds? You timed that wrong. Maybe you made a typo, like timing the wrong function or putting parentheses instead of brackets around your comprehension.

Comment: Yep, typo, iterated through the large `list` but `sum()`ed the original small `list`. /sigh.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I expect your corrected runtime report in a few months :-P

Comment: It took a long time. Gotta run, the Doc's waiting for me at the old clock tower.

Answer (score 3):

This gives what you need:

```
x = [3, 5, 2, 7]
y = [sum(x[0:i]) for i,value in enumerate(x)]
[0, 3, 8, 10]
```

Comment: Thank you for helping with answering the question.  It is also nice if you describe why your solution works so that the asker can gain a better understanding of what is happening.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one sweet one I just discovered:

```
s = 0
cumsum = [(s:=s+i) for i in my_list]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing computation on lists, you may be better using numpy:

```
import numpy as np
x = [3, 5, 2, 7]

print(np.cumsum([0]+x[:-1]).tolist())
[0, 3, 8, 10]
```

Or if 0 is irrelevant:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([3, 5, 2, 7])

print( x[:-1].cumsum())
[ 3  8 10]
```

Or append if you want the 0:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([3, 5, 2, 7])
out = np.array(0)
print(np.append(out, x[:-1].cumsum()))
[0  3  8 10]
```

Whatever you do there is always a loop somewhere, I would be more worried about writing efficient code than short.

Using just python2 a regular for loop would be efficient:

```
x = [3, 5, 2, 7]

sm = 0
out = []
for ele in x:
    out.append(sm)
    sm += ele
print(out)
[0, 3, 8, 10]
```

Answer (score 1):

A pure list comprehension, O(n) time and O(1) extra space (i.e., other than what the list comprehension needs to build the list) ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/v6JYwVYh2lhHwVRHwUhHwTyWi6sSLFTJpQAGaflFCsUKmXkK0QaxSEIVIKGKYiSRSrCi4lgMfcUK2goVsUCDC4oy80o0Kos1//8HAA)):

```
xs = [3, 5, 2, 7]
                           #  Equivalent for-loop version:
ys = [y                    #  ys = []
      for s in [0]         #  s = 0
      for x in xs          #  for x in xs:
      for y in [s]         #      y = s
      for s in [s + x]]    #      s = s + x
                           #      ys.append(y)
print(ys)
```

I renamed to plural `xs` and `ys` so that I can name the single values `x` and `y`. My `s` is the cumulative sum, and I remember it as `y` before updating `s` (because you asked for result `[0, 3, 8, 10]` instead of `[3, 8, 10, 17]`).

Note that since CPython 3.9, my `for y in [s]` and `for s in [s + x]` are optimized so that they don't actually build and iterate single-element lists but work just like `y = s` and `s = s + x`:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis('''ys = [y
...       for s in [0]
...       for x in xs
...       for y in [s]
...       for s in [s + x]]''')

             ...

  4          16 LOAD_FAST                1 (s)
             18 STORE_FAST               3 (y)

  5          20 LOAD_FAST                1 (s)
             22 LOAD_FAST                2 (x)
             24 BINARY_ADD
             26 STORE_FAST               1 (s)

             ...
```

Comment: Great answer, generator friendly comprehension, exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

```
x = [3, 5, 2, 7]

cumsumx=[sum(x[:i] for i in range(len(x))]
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution with [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) in the style of [functional programming](https://realpython.com/python-functional-programming/).

`reduce()` accepts three args: a `function`, an `iterable`, and an `initializer`. The callable `function` takes two args `ret` and `val`, where `ret` is the return value from the previous call. `initializer` is optional, but we need to pass a list `[0]` in this case as the initial `ret` such that further elements can be appended. As for the `iterable`, we pass `nums` excluding the very last element, because it is not used in the cumulative sum.

```py
import functools


def expand(sum_list, val):
    sum_list.append(sum_list[-1] + val)
    return sum_list


nums = [3, 5, 2, 7]
cumulative_sum = functools.reduce(expand, nums[:-1], [0])
```